# Where can I ask questions about being hacked / compromised?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a SE site suitable to ask questions regarding a hacked/compromised server?

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77438234/suspicious-files-found-on-server-in-wordpress-project-wp-admin-user) where the OP's [WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress) site has been compromised, and while I am pretty sure [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) is not the correct SE site, are *[Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/tour)*, *[Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/tour)*, or *[WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)* suitable?

Answer (score 2):

I would say *[WordPress Development](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour)* is the best place for it, as [Strings of malicious code to look for after a hack](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/415508/67532) and [Verifying that I have fully removed a WordPress hack?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/19696/67532) seem related.

Comment: *"every question about theme and plugin development, development and management best practices and server configuration for WordPress"*

Comment: Related question (on its meta site): *[Isn't WordPress Answers meant to house all WordPress questions?](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1230/isnt-wordpress-answers-meant-to-house-all-wordpress-questions/1231#1231)*: *"If removing WordPress from the question means it won't make any sense at all (i.e. you're asking about core WP functionality or how a specific plugin modifies the markup of a page) then it would be on-topic."*

Comment: The particular question *seems* to be borderline on-topic on *WordPress Development*. BTW, Atwood *effectively* didn't have *any* backup of his blog content: *[Coding Horror server crashes losing all data and there are no backups](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/adq8j/coding_horror_server_crashes_losing_all_data_and/)*. E.g. *"all my backups were on the server itself."*